# PHP Imagick converting SVG without antialiasing

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a PHP function to convert an SVG image without any antialiasing (so that the final PNG is blocky and contains only the colours specified in the SVG).

The command line equivalent is:

```
convert +antialias /path/to.svg /path/to.png
```

I'm assuming that I need to use PHP's [Imagick::setOption](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setoption.php) method to pass in "+antialias", but the documentation is very sparse.

The following snippet will write a PNG file, but none of the options prevents antialiased pixels being rendered:

```
$image = new Imagick();

// None of these have any affect - output image is always antialiased.
$image->setOption('+antialias', true);
$image->setOption('-antialias', true);
$image->setOption('+antialias', 'true');
$image->setOption('-antialias', 'true');
$image->setOption('antialias', true);
$image->setOption('antialias', false);
$image->setOption('antialias', 'true');
$image->setOption('antialias', 'false');

$image->readImage('/path/to.svg');
$image->writeImage('/path/to.png');
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a good way to anti-alias a vector file such as SVG. The proper way in command line would be to set the desired density before reading the file and then resize back to compensate for a large magnification when using a large density. So for example

```
convert -density 288 image.svg -resize 25% image.png
```

Nominal density (default) is 72. So 288 = 72*4. Thus we resize afterwards by 1/4 = 25%, unless you want a larger output. Then resize by a larger value.

In PHP Imagick, you can create a new Imagick() instance. Then set the desired density. Then read the input SVG. Then resize. Then set the PNG format and save to disk. See setImageResolution for setting the density in Imagick. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want is possible, unfortunately. ImageMagick shells out to Inkscape to render SVGs, and Inkscape has no command-line option to disable antialiasing.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138075/export-svg-without-anti-aliasing-in-inkscape-1-0-by-command-line

You could render at high resolution and then do nearest-neighbour downsampling. It would reduce the visible antialiasing, but you would still get some colours not in the SVG file.